# How to get the Max value from the subquery in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM passenger
WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(PassengerId) as total_passengers, Sex 
        FROM passenger
        WHERE SibSp > 0
        GROUP BY 2
        ORDER BY 1)
```

I have to determine whether the `count of male or female` was more in my dataset who had `atleast 1` `SibSp`

When I execute the subquery I get Male and Female count as required.
How do I choose the max count from my subquery?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery. Just use the grouped query and add LIMIT 1 to get the first row, which has the max count.

```
SELECT Sex, COUNT(*) AS total_passengers
FROM passenger
WHERE SibSp > 0
GROUP BY Sex
ORDER BY total_passengers DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thankss! 
Ok yeah this was my first thought, but can I not solve this using subquery? just trying to understand more ways to approach a question...

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do with the subquery. Do you want to get all the male passengers if males have the higher count? Your `WHERE` clause isn't comparing anything.

Comment: Hmm Ok.. I get you.. thank you :)